# No member function declaration in class template

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, g++, syntax-error

I have a template class named `SkipList` and a nested class named `Iterator` in it.

`SkipList` follows the following definition:

```
template <typename Key_T, typename Mapped_T, size_t MaxLevel = 5>
class SkipList
{
  typedef std::pair<Key_T, Mapped_T> ValueType;


public:

  class Iterator
  {
      Iterator (const Iterator &);
      Iterator &operator=(const Iterator &);
      Iterator &operator++();
      Iterator operator++(int);
      Iterator &operator--();
      Iterator operator--(int);

    private:
      //some members
  };
```

`Iterator` has a copy constructor and I am declaring it outside the class after its definition like this:

```
template <typename Key_T, typename Mapped_T,size_t MaxLevel>
SkipList<Key_T,Mapped_T,MaxLevel>::Iterator(const SkipList<Key_T,Mapped_T,MaxLevel>::Iterator &that)
```

But I get the following error:

```
SkipList.cpp:134:100: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘Iterator’ with no type [-fpermissive]
SkipList.cpp:134:100: error: no ‘int SkipList<Key_T, Mapped_T, MaxLevel>::Iterator(const SkipList<Key_T, Mapped_T, MaxLevel>::Iterator&)’ member function declared in class ‘SkipList<Key_T, Mapped_T, MaxLevel>’
```

What is wrong?

Comment: How about an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)?

Comment: @AndyProwl I have changed the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
template <typename Key_T, typename Mapped_T,size_t MaxLevel>
SkipList<Key_T,Mapped_T,MaxLevel>::Iterator::Iterator
   (const SkipList<Key_T,Mapped_T,MaxLevel>::Iterator &that) { ...
```

You forgot to qualify the Iterator copy constructor with `SkipList::Iterator::Iterator`, so it is looking for a SkipList member function called `SkipList::Iterator`, hence the error "no member function".